# .NET file commands - suddenly starting 2 weeks ago .net File.Copy and File.Delete started locking files on network shares- and not releasing

Tags: vb.net

25 year old vb.net code. Same code hasn't changed for years. Suddenly starting at about 2-3 weeks ago any File.Copy() or File.Delete() - these are root .net functions-  started locking files. Never releases lock. I have to go on fileshare look for open files and release lock. Every time. All my programs are crashing. Anyone else having problems with .net file commands?   Crazy. This is happening on fileshare drives and administrative shares.

I re-wrote one function using cmd.exe running Robocopy instead of File.Copy and that worked. The problem is not permissions. Robocopy works. File.Copy does not. I ran this in debug mode and compiled. Both lock files. Everything was compiled on Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019

Here is an example that locks a file. It creates the file writes a line and closes the file then when it gets to x = 2 and tries to delete file- it throws an exception saying file is locked. I have to go in and close the open file on the fileserver. If I switch the location to a local drive location like c:\temp- this code works perfectly. No locks, no errors.

```
Imports System.IO
    Try
        Dim StrWriter As StreamWriter
        Dim x As Integer
        For x = 1 To 5
            If File.Exists("\\fs1\public1\LogFile.txt") Then
                File.Delete("\\fs1\public1\\LogFile.txt")
            End If
            StrWriter = File.CreateText("\\fs1\public1\\LogFile.txt")
            StrWriter.WriteLine("Hello")
            StrWriter.Close()
        Next


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Don't call `File.Exists()`. There are a number of "gotchas" around it. Instead, just `try` to the delete file and handle the exception if it fails. Thanks to file system volatility, you need to be prepared for the exception anyway. Or, in this case, just call the `File.Create()` overload that lets you tell it to always create new and overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this issue- it's not anything to do with programming. It is from anti-virus software. My AV software was randomly locking files on the fileshare that my program was copying or trying to delete.

Answer (score 0):

The [`File.CreateText()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext) includes this info:

> Creates or opens a file for writing UTF-8 encoded text. If the file already exists, its contents are overwritten.

Therefore the `Exists()` and `Delete()` code are not necessary at all. If the file already exists, we can call `CreateText()` with no other checks and any existing file is replaced (deleted) automatically. Everything can reduce to this:

```
Try
   Using writer As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(@"\\fs1\public1\LogFile.txt")
        writer.WriteLine("Hello")
   End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

This will also *likely* (no guarantees) fix the issue in the question. The reason is the most likely source was an exception or other failure to reach or fully execute the `StrWriter.Close()` line, such that the stream was left open. The `Using` block makes stronger guarantees about disposing the stream. You should also track down other code which writes to this log file and update it to also use `Using` block.

It's also possible the issue is external to the code: whoever is responsible for monitoring this log file is using a new tool that locks the file while they have it open, and they are leaving this tool running in the background. Or maybe it's the same tool, but the behavior changed, where now they leave it running when before they would have closed it.

One other thing to mention is it's now better practice to use a fully-qualified name for the server. Instead of just `fs1`, use something like `fs1.myADdomain.example`.  This helps speed name resolution, makes it less likely for authentication to fall back to older/weaker mechanisms, and is one part of allowing better-encrypted traffic between the client and server.

Comment: I did exactly what you said- same exact issue. Removed all the Exists() and Delete() just used File.CreateText and error was same: "The process cannot access the file '\\fs1\public1\LogFile.txt' because it is being used by another process." File share shows file locked for writing by me. If I 'close open file' on fileserver I can delete file fine.

Comment: Something is holding it open. You'll need to ensure the file is closed first, and then you can test this. And the only place to do that is from the `fs1` server.

Comment: yeah- but this happens when I create a one-off file. Nothing is touching that file but this code. So strange.

Comment: Even copying a file locks- this code locks LogFile2.txt         File.Copy("\\fs1.domain.com\public1\LogFile.txt", "\\fs1.domain.com\public1\LogFile2.txt")

Comment: That sounds like an issue on the server end of the file share.

Comment: Joel- thanks for all your help. I have finally figured it out. Stupid anti-virus was locking everything- randomly and only on some computers and not others. Turn off anti-virus everywhere- everything works now. I'll delete this question since it has nothing to do with programing- just wanted to thank you. You pointed me in right direction.

Comment: Keep the question up and add the anti-virus check as an answer. It's still possible another programmer runs into this issue in the future.